# jquery .clone() versus id and name attributes

Tags: jquery

I've read a number of questions and answers in this area, but none of them seem to get to the meat (or potatos) of the problem at hand.

If you point .clone() at an element with an id and/or a name, with children with ids and/or names, what do you get? Items with no id or name? Items that violate the dom's rules by duplicating ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `.clone()` by itself does not violate any of the DOM's rules (`.clone()` is just a function call, the results exist in memory).

Inserting the results of the `.clone()` call into the DOM, however, will cause two element's with the same `id` to exist in the document (which as you point out is invalid).

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have summed it up nicely, but here is a method to remove `id` attributes in a fresh clone...

```
clone.find('[id]').removeAttr('id');
```

Alternatively, if you want to add a string to their `id` attributes...

```
clone.find('[id]').attr('id', function(index, oldId) { return oldId + 'cloned'; });
```

Answer (score 0):

The cloned elements aren't inserted into DOM just yet. They exist only in memory and as such they don't violate any specification. That's my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple elements can have the same `name`, so that isn't a problem.

Calling `clone` on an element does not in itself violate the DOM rule of unique IDs.  This is because the clone of the element is not currently *in* the document.  The rule is only broken if and when you insert it.